# How to test for missing attribute in XSL?

Tags: xslt, xpath

What I have is following:

```
<xsl:variable name="myvar" select=".//spss:category[((not @varName) or @varName=$colVarName) and @text=$series]/spss:cell/@text"/>
```

What it *should* do is select the text of the `spss:cell`'s text-Attribute as long as it is a child of a `spss:category` that has

- either a `varName` Attribute with a value equal to `$colVarName`
- *OR* no `varName` Attribute at all

What *is* happening is following error message (sorry translating here, so just the gist of it):

> Expected Token ')'. Found Token '@'.
>   .//spss:category[((not  -->@<-- varName) or @varName=$colVarName...

**Problem Solved!** (See below)

Comment: Then delete your question in order not to mislead people to spend time on it

Comment: Dimitre, I can only accept my own answer 48 hours from now. I allready tried that. Also, I would like to keep this in the system, since it was not obviously found by google (the only post I found to the question I asked had the wrong syntax!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I think I found the mistake:

`not` must be used with parenthesis, so instead of

```
(not @varName) or @varName=$colVarName
```

it should have been

```
not(@varName) or @varName=$colVarName
```

Answer (score 2):

indeed - `not()` is a function that returns the boolean opposite of whatever is between the parens. If necessary - it will cast its argument to a boolean. In this case, an empty node set casts automatically to false, so if `@varName` gives you an empty node set, `not(@varName)` will be true.